# WPF Windows shortcut help

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

I'm developing a XAML system which at present involves an icon in the taskbar which the user has to hover over in order to open the main window. However I need to take accessibility into consideration due to legal issues and also making the system appeal to as broad a range of users as possible. In order to make the system more accessible I am in the process of trying to create a windows shortcut which will allow the main program window to be opened from anywhere else in windows.

The code I've been working on, has 2 faults, the first is that the event handler only fires if the application itself is the focus, where as the shortcuts I require must be able to be opended while other windows are in focus etc. The second is that in the event handler it doesn't detect Alt & Q being pressed at the same time. The code I've created can be found below, I'm just looking for a way to handle the shortcut Alt & Q from anywhere in the windows enviroment and detect them buttons have been pressed, so the window can open.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

```
this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(this.Window_Keydown);

private void Window_Keydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt) && (e.Key == Key.Q)){}
    }
```

Comment: So you want to catch all keystrokes in the system? Even when your application has not the focus, or is minimized?

Comment: Yes, this is due to the way the system works, with the users having to use a mouse to hover over a small icon in the taskbar which then opens the application. This will pose a challange for blind users so I'm looking to create a shortcut to open the window when a user presses them.

Comment: I think I've found a way of doing this but its a bit of a hack job as it involes adding the system.windows.forms namespace and using a hook into the microsoft keyboard commands that I found on CodeProject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two comments:

Firstly, I would get rid of the "hover" requirement. If you use a standard method of adding your app to the taskbar, such as using System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon, you should have your application Window open when it is double clicked. Optionally, you could also add a right click context menu. This way a user can use winkey+B to go to the system tray, and left/right to find your icon, enter to double click or applicationkey to right click.

If, for some reason, this doesn't work in your particular scenario. I would recommend checking if your application is running in the Application_Start event (this only works if you want a single instance of your application at any time). So, if a user runs the application, and there's already an instance of the application open, just restore the window state and bring it to the foreground.

Then, during the installation you can set up a standard Windows shortcut on the desktop or start menu, and set a hotkey in the shortcut properties (this can all be done in code). Then, when the user types the shortcut key, the shortcut will launch the app, Application_Start will execute, it'll see there's a version already running (in the task bar) and bring it to the foreground. Thus achieving the same result in a more standard way.

I hope I correctly understood what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that winkey + B did that and it achieves what I wanted really without the shortcut key, although I have also got that working.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should take a look at `RoutedCommand` objects, and the [InputGestures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.inputgestures.aspx) property

Here is the MSDN of RoutedCommands and how to set it up:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.aspx

Basicly you have a command: ProcessDataCommand

```
public class MyCommands
{ 
    public static readonly RoutedCommand ProcessDataCommand = new RoutedCommand();
}
```

Set it to your menuitem or button as follows:

```
<Button Command="{x:Static NameSpace:MyCommands.ProcessDataCommand}" />
```

And add a `CommandBinding` to the control you wish to handle your command:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.aspx

```
<Window x:Class="WCSamples.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="CloseCommand"
    Name="RootWindow"
    >
  <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static NameSpace:MyCommands.ProcessDataCommand}"
                    Executed="CloseCommandHandler"
                    CanExecute="CanExecuteHandler"
                    />
  </Window.CommandBindings>
  <StackPanel Name="MainStackPanel">
    <Button Command="{x:Static NameSpace:MyCommands.ProcessDataCommand}" 
            Content="Close File" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Now for the shortkey magic ;)

Where you defined your command, add the following static constructor:

```
static MyCommands()
{
    ProcessDataCommand.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.Q, ModifierKeys.Alt));
}
```

And your command will respond to the shortkey as well!

Download a routed command sample here:
http://www.codeplex.com/wpfroutedcommand

Hope this helps

Comment: A bit but im not doing anything within the application itself, just attempting to open the main window while the application is minimized.

Comment: Ahh you might want to take a look at a Keyboard hook invoked with P/Invoke! Someone wrote a simple keylogger in C# using this technique, perhaps you can extract the things you need: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSLLKeyboardHook.aspx .

Comment: Ah I see you already found that article.. You dont need Windows Form to make it work btw ;) if you can recognize the ints the keys throw, you can do without the forms dll. P/Invoke is located in the System.Runtime namespace